# Unable to call save method in Breeze controller

Tags: breeze, single-page-application, durandal

I am working on Single Page application using Durandal framework. I want to call save method explicitly from Breeze controller. So to call save method explicitly, I was trying to set entity state modified in below way, but still I am unable to call save method in Breeze controller.

```
SelectedModelData().Model.entityAspect.entityState.name = "Changed";
SelectedModelData().Model.entityAspect.entityState.isModified = true;
```

SelectedModelData() is observable. And Model is entity inside that observable.

Comment: Kindly format code using 4 spaces, so that it will distinguised from question.

Comment: if model is observable too then I think you want: SelectedModelData().Model().entityAspect.entityState.name = "Changed";

Answer (score 0):

The EntityState values are like Enums, so you can't just change the name.  The correct way is:

```
SelectedModelData().Model.entityAspect.setModified();
```

or

```
SelectedModelData().Model.entityAspect.setEntityState(breeze.EntityState.Modified);
```

See http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/inside-entity.html#EntityState for more info.